# android - how to get total memory usage of the application at runtime?

Tags: android, memory-management, process

i know that there are multiple solutions and questions regarding this issue , but none that i've tested have worked on all android versions , including honeycomb and ice cream sandwich.

as an example, i've created an app that uses more and more memory , and used  "Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()" to get the memory usage , but it returns a relatively constant number on the motorola xoom (even when i get out-of-memory error) , yet a changing number on the nexus one .

what is the best way to get the total memory used by the application's process (inside the code , not via ddms)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to discover memory usage of my application in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android)

Comment: did you read what i've written? i haven't succeeded using any of the solutions i've found . this is a very popular post which i've tested , and even this doesn't work . please try to use it on multiple APIs (including honecomb and gingerbread) and get the available memory after each time you create a new bitmap (till the out-of-memory error) and see that it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: "did you read what i've written?" -- yes, I did. "i haven't succeeded using any of the solutions i've found" -- that's nice. The solution you listed is not in the post I cited, and you did not cite anything else that you tried. If you read the post I cited, you will note that Ms. Hackborn (one of the core Android developers) says "the chances of you actually correctly interpreting whatever numbers you get is extremely low"... and that's even for the Android developer team.

Comment: Hence, whatever problem you are trying to solve by getting "the total memory used by the application's process" will need to be solved in some other way, in all likelihood.

Comment: so you are saying that such a thing is impossible?

Comment: I am saying that if you truly applied all the techniques from Ms. Hackborn's answer, and none of them work for you (or are not precisely relevant for your situation), that I would recommend that you approach whatever your problem is from some other angle.

Comment: you probably mean "hackbod" . anyway , he/she didn't show a working solution via java code . the most important thing , it isn't mentioned which of the fields there belong to the one that gives you the available/taken memory by the app/process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method below, this will tell you the free memory available to your DVM:

Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

Comment: doesn't work - keeps getting the same size for both gingerbread and honeycomb on my test.